# Lua find and extract tags within a string

Tags: lua

I feel questions similar to this have been asked previously but not related to html like tags or in Lua 5.4.

I have a string `<NS>my_file_path.py</NS> <NS>count</NS> <NS>type: :model</NS> <TS>do some counting</TS>` and ideally I'll be able to pick specific tags (and everything between it) such as `<NS>type: :model</NS>`, and remove it from the string before doing any further formatting.

I'm guessing some matching with `<NS>type:` would be a start but how I stop at `</NS>` is the confusing part!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: [Do not attempt to parse HTML (or XML) with RegEx (or Lua patterns). Use libraries instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7185318)

*However,* if you're only interested in removing innermost tags (i.e. "leaf" tags; tags without children), your tags are strictly formatted in this simple fashing as in your example (no `<tag spacing or attributes inside="tag"  >` allowed) and the scope of your project is *very* limited, you could use `string.gsub` and a pattern to remove these tags:

```lua
str = str:gsub("<NS>type:.-</NS>", "")
```

Pattern explanation:

- find substrings starting with `"<NS>type:"`
- allow for arbitrary content - zero or more arbitrary characters (`.`); note that this has to be lazy (`-`) instead of greedy (`*`) to work
- stop matching the substring at the first occurrence of `</NS>`, closing the tag; if you used a greedy quantifier before, this would have stopped at the *last* occurrence of `</NS>`, exceeding the tag

Comment: What does the `.` mean between `type:` and `-`?

Comment: @noobmaster69 `.` means "any character". See [the Lua 5.4 reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1).